# Is there a source for all of the most common video codecs in one single distribution?

Tags: windows, codec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best free codec pack](https://superuser.com/questions/5184/best-free-codec-pack)

I am looking for a windows xp codec distribution that contains all of the standard codec types to load on a new computer. I would rather not have to install them each separately.

Anyone know a good source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/), the Combined Community Codec Pack.  As a caveat, some of the A/V experts warn against these things, saying they break stuff, but I haven't run into problems.

Comment: I have always used CCCP with no issues. It's one of the first things to be installed on a fresh copy of Windows.

Comment: CCCP is very clean and only includes what's really necessary. If you're interested, here's a list of what it installs: http://www.cccp-project.net/wiki/index.php?title=Advanced_FAQ#Exactly_what_does_the_CCCP_install_and_why.3F

Answer (score 2):

[Zoomplayer](http://www.inmatrix.com/products.shtml) includes an "Install center" which will automatically download a hand-picked selection of codecs and codec-versions that work well together and give you the best coverage.

It will also be able to update these without breaking anything if you rerun "Install center" at a later time. During the initial install it will also detect codecs already installed and only update those that need to for it all to work in harmony.

This is what I always use these days, it has never failed me. Installing random codec packs or some multi-mega-pack from other sources seems to easily end in a lot of hurt sooner or later...

...as Zoomplayer these days is commercial (free trial includes the "Install center" though) they have to have a near-perfect selection of codecs as I bet they have to support it as well? ^^

Answer (score 2):

I've always used the [K-Lite](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_lite_codec_pack.htm) codec pack.